# How to create a s3 object download link once file uploaded to bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a requirement where after multiple files (json,txt) are uploaded to S3 bucket, a download link should be generated for each object and to be shared with user on email.
I was able to create a python script to upload files from my local ubuntu system to my s3 bucket with public access to all the objects.
Any assistance or link guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to generate the download link, just append the path to your file to your bucket's URL. Also make sure that you set permissions correctly.

Comment: Format: `https://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/KEY`